# System Verilog parameterise class with interface

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification, hdl

A protocol may be implemented over different physical layers, e.g.

```
interface async_if;
    logic tx;

    task send(int n);
        tx <= 0; // stop bit
        #10;
        // etc.
    endtask
endinterface

interface clkd_if;
    logic data;
    logic clk;

    task send(int n);
        foreach(n[ii]) begin
            data <= n[ii];
            clk <= 1;
            #10 clk <= 0;
            #10 ;
        end endtask
endinterface
```

Is there a way of parameterising a System Verilog class with an interface? The following doesn't seem to compile, because System Verilog doesn't regard interfaces as types.

```
class sender#(type I);
    virtual I if;
    function void send(int n);
        if.send(n);
    endfunction
endclass
```

Comment: Strangely enough, an interface is not a type, but a virtual interface is.

Answer (score 2):

You can parameterise a class with an interface in SystemVerilog. You  just weren't doing it quite right. This works:

```
  class sender #(type I);
    I vif;  // 'if' is a reserved word and you don't want the 'virtual' here
    function void send(int n);
        vif.send(n);
    endfunction     
  endclass
```

Then you can:

```
  sender#(virtual async_if) s = new;
```

---

https://www.edaplayground.com/home

```
module M;

  interface async_if;
    logic tx;

    task send(int n);
        tx <= 0; // stop bit
        #10;
        // etc.
    endtask
  endinterface

  interface clkd_if;
    logic data;
    logic clk;

    task send(int n);
        foreach(n[ii]) begin
            data <= n[ii];
            clk <= 1;
            #10 clk <= 0;
            #10 ;
        end
    endtask
  endinterface

  class sender #(type I);
    I vif;
    function void send(int n);
        vif.send(n);
    endfunction     
  endclass

  sender#(virtual async_if) s = new;

endmodule
```

Comment: That's not an interface. That's a virtual interface.

Comment: @user234461 What do you want to do that the above solution isn't solving?

Comment: That's irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

No, because as you said, it does not a data type (see the [SystemVerilog LRM](https://www.accellera.org/downloads/ieee) section A.2.2.1 for what is considered a data type).

Not sure what your use case is, but it looks very much like [polymorphic interfaces](http://verificationhorizons.verificationacademy.com/volume-7_issue-3/articles/stream/polymorphic-interfaces-an-alternative-for-systemverilog-interfaces_vh-v7-i3.pdf) is what you want. It involves embedding a class inside the interface that implements methods of a base `virtual class`.